# Map sequence in Rx.JS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I would like to map correct sequence using Rx.js.
A simplest example will be using keyboard. I attach Rx.js to keyboard events and waiting for three A no matter what will be between them, except Q. When sequence is matched I would like to print OK on console.
For example:

- AAA -> should print OK
- AsssAqweA  -> should print OK
- AAQAAQ -> shouldn't print anything
- AAQAAA -> should print OK
- AAAsssAAAsssAAA -> should print three times OK

Should I use filter function and keep state inside it? Or there is an esier way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `filter` and `scan` operators to do what you want:

```js
Rx.Observable.from("AsssAqweAbAAQAAA")

  // Only A and Q characters are important:

  .filter(char => (char === "A") || (char === "Q"))

  // Accumulate the A characters until there are three
  // or until a Q is received:

  .scan((acc, char) => {
    if ((char === "Q") || (acc.length === 3)) {
      acc = [];
    }
    if (char === "A") {
      acc.push(char);
    }    
    return acc;
  }, [])

  // Filter the accumulated characters until there
  // are three:

  .filter(acc => acc.length === 3)
  .mapTo("OK")
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with a `bufferCount` - though I'm not certain if your given examples are simplified and in reality a little more complex, but maybe this helps:

```js
const source$ = Rx.Observable.from("aaqassaaassaaa");
source$.bufferCount(3, 1)
  // .do(console.log) // uncomment to see the processed data
  .filter(data => data.join("") === "aaa") // your detection-logic
  .mapTo("Ok")
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Buffer count for my example `AsssAqwweA`. I was thinking about using it, but it fails on this example.

Comment: Ah I see, yes i missed that, sorry